# get the checked item in the arraylist

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-lists

I am trying to make a app in which i have used a custom list.The list contains text view  and checkbox.The list contains few 30-40 datas in it.Now what i want is that i when user checks on a particular checkbox,the associated data with that checkbox should be added to the arrayList.I tried it but when i scroll my list the data from the list disapperas.Why this is happening

COde

```
public class EmailListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<EmailModel> data;
    DbHandler dbHandler;
    int[] emails;
    ArrayList<String> emailSeperated;

    public EmailListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<EmailModel> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        emails = new int[data.size()];
    }

    @Override

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        dbHandler = new DbHandler(context);
        emailSeperated = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.email_custom_list, viewGroup, false);
            holder.tvContact = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_email_name);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_email_checkbox);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
//        if (emails[i] == 0) {
//            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
//        } else {
//            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
//        }

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                                                       @Override
                                                       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                                                           if (compoundButton == holder.checkBox) {
                                                               if (b) {
                                                                   emails[i] = 1;
                                                                   //dbHandler.updateContactList(data.get(i).getUserID(), 1);
//                                                                   emailSeperated.add(data.get(i).getEmail());
//                                                                   Log.e("Email values", emailSeperated.toString());
//                                                                   ShareWithinpocketDocs.etEmailLists.setText(emailSeperated.toString());

//

                                                               } else {
                                                                   emails[i] = 0;
//                                                                   emailSeperated.remove(data.get(i).getEmail());
//                                                                   Log.e("Email values", emailSeperated.toString());


                                                               }
                                                           }

                                                       }
                                                   }

        );


        if (emails[i] == 0) {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
            emailSeperated.remove(data.get(i).getEmail());
            Log.e("Email values", emailSeperated.toString());
            ShareWithinpocketDocs.etEmailLists.setText(emailSeperated.toString());
        } else {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
            emailSeperated.add(data.get(i).getEmail());
            Log.e("Email values", emailSeperated.toString());
            ShareWithinpocketDocs.etEmailLists.setText(emailSeperated.toString());
        }


        holder.tvContact.setText(data.get(i).getEmail());


        return view;
    }


    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvContact;
        CheckBox checkBox;

    }
}
```

When ever user scrolls the list, the data in the array is deleted.Y such is happening?

Comment: Your problem is related to the View Recycling. The adapter use the list to refresh the view for performance scope. I think that you must use another List ( not in the adapter, maybe in the activity/fragment ) and use it to store the checked values.

Comment: `the data from the list disapperas. Why this is happening` explain it a bit further ? what list do you mean?

Comment: @phemt.latd how can i achieve it sir???

Comment: @mmlooloo Sir when ever i scrool the list the data is being refressed according to the views